# AndroidPermission rational being shown AFTER request, not before

Tags: android, react-native, permissions

I'm working on a react-native app which needs to record audio. I'm using the following code to request permission to do so,

```
const permissionRequestReason = {
    title: 'Permission To Record Audio',
    message: 'Explain reason for audio recording here....',
    buttonPositive: 'Continue'
}

export default AudioRecorder = {
    record: async function () {
        try {
            if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
                const permission = await PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO);
                if (permission == false) {
                    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO,
                        permissionRequestReason
                    );
                    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                        if(__DEV__) console.log("WE HAVE AUDIO RECORD PERMISSION");
                    }
                } else {
                    if(__DEV__) console.log("WE HAVE AUDIO RECORD PERMISSION");
                }
            } else {
                if(__DEV__) console.log("iOS, so lets record");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            if(__DEV__) console.log("ERROR REQUESTING AUDIO RECORD PERMISSION: " + error)
        }
    },
}
```

My problem is that the first time I request permission, the rational message is not being shown. I only get the standard Android audio permission box. If I click deny on this, and then request the permission again, THEN I get the rational dialogue. Anyone know why I'm not getting it the first time?

Comment: _"Anyone know why I'm not getting it the first time?"_ That's how `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` works. If you want to show the rationale before the first request you'll have to implement that yourself (i.e. keep track of whether you've ever requested the permission).

Comment: Oh. Well don't I feel the fool :p. I thought I could use it to explain why I'm requesting permissions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Michael pointed out in his comment, this is the expected behaviour, so the mistake was my expectation of what the code was supposed to. Therefore marking this as solved.[edit] or at least I will do in 2 days which is how long I have to wait before I'm allowed to mark this as the answer :p.